# Retrieving redundant entries of listed elements contained in make variables

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have got e.g . a list of source-files assigned to a variable within as makefile and would like
to figure out at build time, whether there are entries twice listed which could trouble the build process and its result:

Example:

```
ListofSource = ./a/hello.c ./b/sys.c ./c/input.c ./d/hello.c
```

How is it possible to analyse/filter ListofSource retrieving a list

```
DuplicateSources = ./a/hello.c ./d/hello.c
```

Function $(sort list) sorts a list and removes redundant entries, I need the opposite behaviour. 
Does there exist any make functionality which could be applied?

Answer (score 0):

If you're obsessive about Makefile tidiness, you could require that the list be in sorted order and do something like:

```
ifneq ($(LIST),$(sort $(LIST)))
$(error $$(LIST) contains duplicates)
endif
```

Comment: This fails when ${LIST} is not sorted, yet is without duplcates. I suggest you need to compare the output of `$(words...)`: `ifneq ($(words ${LIST}),$(words $(sort ${LIST})))...`. (Oh, and your test is the wrong way round.)

Comment: @bobbogo: You're correct about the test being the wrong way around, but what part of "you could require that the list be in sorted order" did you not see? The use of `$(words)` is not a terrible idea, but you don't use `${}` to expand variables in `make`.

Comment: Oh yes you do! I usually reserve `$()` for functions, and `${}` for user variables (too much perl methinks). Improves readability IMHO. You are right about the wording. As far as the list required to be in sorted order, yet maintaining duplicates goes, that would be a question in itself!

Comment: @bobbogo: Huh, I guess you can: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/make.html . I'm sufficiently obsessive about the sort order in my Makefile variables that I could probably rely on the `$(sort)` trick, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$(shell)`, e.g.

```
DuplicateSources = $(shell perl -e '++$c{$_} for @ARGV; print join(" ",grep{$c{$_}>1} sort keys %c),"\n"' $(ListofSource))
```

should work.

Comment: If you're going to use `$(shell)`, use `:=` instead of `=`, to force immediate expansion. You don't want to be invoking perl every time `$(DuplicateSources)` is referenced.

Comment: Good point, I thought about it but I didn't want to explain the difference :)

Answer (score 0):

`$(shell...)` is not recommended when you can do it all in make.

```
list := a/1 b/2 c/3 a/1
duplicates := $(foreach v,$(sort ${list}),$(if $(filter-out 1,$(words $(filter $v,${list}))),$v))
```

(Naturally this can be cleaned up a bit.) Such expressions are best read from the inside to out.

- `$v` is set to each item in the list in turn. No duplicates here as we use `$(sort...)`
- `$(filter $v,${list})` returns all the items that match `$v`. Generally there will be exactly one return value, but in this example, when `$v` is `a/1` we get two (identical) values.
- Then we count the words in the previous. Generally `$(words...)` will return 1, or a higher number in the case of duplicates.
- We aren't interested when `$(words...)` returns 1, so we `$(filter-out...)` these cases.
- Anything left is a duplicate! So using `$(if...)` we return `$v` in this case.

There are other ways using `$(eval...)` which gives you genuine programming opportunities.